# Process events one at a time in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Lets consider the following stream

```
  SomeState state = new SomeState().

 _refreshFiberStream =
    Stream()
    .SubscribeOn(new EventLoopScheduler()) 
    .Select(DoCalc)
    .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
    .Subscribe(Update);
```

The DoCalc method will project into input and consumes 'state' and the resulting output is given to Update method, which would modify the 'state'. If a new event comes in, it should act on state last updated from previous event, and project based on that.

I am looking for a way where the events are always executed in sequence. For example if I have three events I am looking for a way so that they are executed in DoCalc, Update followed by DoCalc, Update followed by DoCalc, Update.

Instead I am seeing DoCalc, DoCalc, Update, Update, DoCalc, Update i.e. they never run in sequence.

Is there a way I can enforce it in Rx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a conflict between the need for *in order execution* on the one hand, and *dispatching to another thread* on the other.  My suggestion is to break `Update` into two parts:

1. the part the needs to be executed in sequence (Update)
2. the part that needs to be dispatched (Dispatch)

Then you can call `Do(Update)` in sequence, and `Subscribe(Dispatch)` on the dispatcher:

```
var result =
    Stream()
        .SubscribeOn(new EventLoopScheduler())
        .Select(DoCalc)
        .Do(Update)
        .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
        .Subscribe(Dispatch);
```

The resulting sequence is like this (the "Dispatch n" calls could occur at any time after "Update n"):

```
    Select a
    Update a
    Select b
    Update b
    Dispatch a
    Dispatch b
```

---

I guess an alternative would be to use a `ManualResetEvent`, which dictates that the next DoCalc can only proceed once the Update has occurred.  You could do this by adding `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` to DoCalc, and `ManualResetEvent.Set` to Update:

```
private ManualResetEvent _wait = new ManualResetEvent(true);

private string DoCalc(string input)
{
    _wait.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Selected {0}", input);
    _wait.Reset();
    return input;
}

private void Update(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Update {0}", input);
    _wait.Set();
}
```

This second approach "works", but thread blocking like this it makes me uneasy -- it seems to work at cross purposes to reactive programming.  And of course, likewise, [it's best to avoid introducing state, if possible.](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/09_SideEffects.html#SideEffects)

Comment: I see a conflict between the need for modify shared state, using Rx, and, adding concurrency ;-)

Comment: @LeeCampbell yes, well said ... the concurrency and the shared state need to be separated somehow.

Comment: @McGarnagle I wanted to avoid thread blocking as it is not right way to do it, and agree that concurrency and shared state don't go together.